# SQL - Return all unique pairs of values from one column, for each value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose the table looks like

```
col1 col2
---- ----
1    a
2    a
3    a
4    b
5    b
6    b
```

and I want to get all pairs from col1 for each value in col2, meaning the result should look like:

```
col1a col1b col2
----  ----- ----
1     2     a
1     3     a
2     3     a
4     5     b
4     6     b
5     6     b
```

I have tried to use

```
temp1 cross join temp2 where temp1.col1 < temp2.col1 order by temp1.col1, temp2.col1
```

as part of the full query, but it's not returning all the possible combinations. Also I'm not sure how I should write the "for each" part of the command, as in "for each value in col2, create all pairs from the value in col1". Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm lost, how are the pairs generated?

Comment: The pairs are just all possible pairings of two things in col1 that are associated with the same value in col2. So for example everything in the set {1,2,3} is in col1, and they are all associated with the value 'a' in col2, so the pairs are {(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
select t1.col1 as col1a, t2.col1 as col1b, t1.col2 
from t as t1
join t as t2 on t1.col2 = t2.col2
where t1.col1 < t2.col1
```

A sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/48b7e/1) gives the same output as your example.

Comment: Thank you, that means what I missed was the condition in " join... on <condition> ", which does grouping based on col2.